# How to color parts of a statusbar? (Winapi)

Tags: c++, winapi

Good day,

I'm writing a GUI for my application in C++, using WinAPI. All working fine, I've got everything I need, including a parted statusbar, except for colorized parts.

[My working GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEDjY.png)

I'm creating the statusbar like this:

```
int statwidths[] = {150, 350, 500, -1};

(...)

case WM_PAINT:
(...)
hStatus = CreateWindowEx(0, STATUSCLASSNAME, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_STATUS, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);        
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"Item:");
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 1, (LPARAM)"Item:");
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 2, (LPARAM)"Setpoint:");
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETTEXT, 3, (LPARAM)"Status");

break;
```

Colorizing the whole thing is fairly easy:

`SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETBKCOLOR, 0, RGB(255,0,0));`

..but that's not what I need. I want to be able to control the color of the individual parts.
I've tried several methods, including this function, found on MSDN:

```
HWND DoCreateStatusBar(HWND hwndParent, int idStatus, HINSTANCE
                      hinst, int cParts)
{
    HWND hwndStatus;
    RECT rcClient;
    HLOCAL hloc;
    PINT paParts;
    int i, nWidth;

    // Ensure that the common control DLL is loaded.
    InitCommonControls();

    // Create the status bar.
    hwndStatus = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                       // no extended styles
        STATUSCLASSNAME,         // name of status bar class
        NULL,           // no text when first created
        SBARS_SIZEGRIP |         // includes a sizing grip
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,   // creates a visible child window
        0, 0, 0, 0,              // ignores size and position
        hwndParent,              // handle to parent window
        (HMENU) idStatus,       // child window identifier
        hinst,                   // handle to application instance
        NULL);                   // no window creation data

    // Get the coordinates of the parent window's client area.
    GetClientRect(hwndParent, &rcClient);

    // Allocate an array for holding the right edge coordinates.
    hloc = LocalAlloc(LHND, sizeof(int) * cParts);
    paParts = (PINT) LocalLock(hloc);

    // Calculate the right edge coordinate for each part, and
    // copy the coordinates to the array.
    nWidth = rcClient.right / cParts;
    int rightEdge = nWidth;
    for (i = 0; i < cParts; i++) {
       paParts[i] = rightEdge;
       rightEdge += nWidth;
    }

    // Tell the status bar to create the window parts.
    SendMessage(hwndStatus, SB_SETPARTS, (WPARAM) cParts, (LPARAM)
               paParts);

    // Free the array, and return.
    LocalUnlock(hloc);
    LocalFree(hloc);
    return hwndStatus;
}
```

I was hoping to be able to play around with several colorized rectangles and get what I need via that way, not working.
Tried to create parts via ownerdraw:
`SendMessage(hStatus1, SB_SETTEXT, 0 | SBT_OWNERDRAW, 0);`
, and deal with setting colors and backgrounds in the WM_DRAWITEM-case, same disappointing result: the statusbar is getting drawn but I'm not able to color it.
I'm able to, for example, colorize the text in a pane with this code in my WM_DRAWITEM:

```
            lpDIS=(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
            ptStr =(PTSTR)lpDIS->itemData;
            SetTextColor(lpDIS->hDC, RGB(0xFF, 00, 00));
            ExtTextOut(lpDIS->hDC, 0, 0, 0 , &lpDIS->rcItem,ptStr, strlen(ptStr), NULL);
```

[which (weirdly) gives me this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRUvy.png)

Tried playing around with bits and pieces that I use to color the background of the main GUI:

```
            HBRUSH brush;
            RECT rect;

            pen=CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, bkgndcolor);
            brush=CreateSolidBrush(bkgndcolor);
            SelectObject((HDC)wParam, pen);
            SelectObject((HDC)wParam, brush);
```

..but then I got stuck. `GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect); Rectangle((HDC)wParam, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);` obviously won't do the trick because "rect" contains the rectangle of the main window, and not the statusbar or a part of it.

Would someone be able to at least point me in the right direction? Searching this forum and the internet got me nowhere; apparently what I want is relatively rare. I cannot imagine it to be impossible though.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to owner-draw the status bar. There is no other way to do per-part coloring. You say you are getting a "disappointing result", but you did not show your drawing code, or a screenshot of what the result looks like, or explain what is "disappointing" about it.

Comment: Edited my post. "Disappointing result" just meant that it wasn't working: not able to control the background-color of a pane. Added some screenshots and some more code. At least good to know that owner-draw is the way forward, would you (or someone) be able to point me a little further into the right direction?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/status-bars#owner-drawn-status-bars

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response, all. I managed to get it working with the following bits and pieces:

Filling my parts with `SBT_OWNERDRAW` in wParam.
My windowprocessing looks like this:

```
(...)
        case WM_DRAWITEM:
            lpDIS=(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
            GetClientRect((HWND)lpDIS->hwndItem, &rect);

            pen=CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, bkgndcolor);
            brush=CreateSolidBrush(bkgndcolor);
            SelectObject(lpDIS->hDC, pen);
            SelectObject(lpDIS->hDC, brush);

            Rectangle(lpDIS->hDC, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);

            ptStr =(PTSTR)lpDIS->itemData;
            SetTextColor(lpDIS->hDC, RGB(0,0,0));
            SetBkColor(lpDIS->hDC, bkgndcolor);
            SetBkMode( lpDIS->hDC, TRANSPARENT );
            DrawText(lpDIS->hDC, ptStr, -1, &rect, DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);
        break;
```

I simply adjust the rect-struct (.left and .right) for every pane so that the rectangle covers it.

[the result is pretty much what I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY7zi.png)

Small remark is that the text is not nicely placed in the pane. I've tried writing the text with `ExtTextOutA` to give it an x- and y-offset but that only writes the string in the left-pane. `DrawText` seems to do the trick for writing in the proper rectangle. To give it some spacing, a quick fix would be to increase rect.left with two. A suggestion for a little less ugly workaround would be highly appreciated.

Another remark would be that the font seems to be different if I owner-draw it: see the screenshot, were #1 till #3 are owner-drawn. Not the biggest problem, but I think I like the "original" font more. Assuming that I have to select this font myself, would anybody happen to know what this font is and how big it needs to be to match the original?

Thanks all!

Comment: You can fix the font issue by sending `WM_GETFONT` to the control to get the correct font and selecting it into the DC (and make sure you restore the previous font after).